# Rename PHP internal command

Tags: php, syntax, programming-languages

Quick simple question guys...

Is it possible to rename INTERNAL php commands ?

For example :

instead of

```
echo '123';
```

I will be able to write this :

```
ScreenDisplay '123';
```

another example :

instad of :

```
if () {}
```

I will be able to write this :

```
myCondition () {}
```

Thanks !

Comment: I guess you will have to change PHP C code and recompile it by yourself

Comment: Just out of curiousity why would you want to do that?

Comment: If you just want an alias, you can make a wrapper. i.e. your functions would look like similar to `function ScreenDesplay($text) { echo $text; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a parser for that in php, which is a silly idea, or implement a php extension module in C++. http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-php-extension-development-via-php-cpp/

There is the Typo3 CMS that comes with a custum script language called Typo3Script which is parsed and executed as php. http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/ You can try to re-use that for your custom script language or whatever you try to do. However, I think implementing yet another script language within php itself is a silly idea.

Answer (score 1):

Go here if you get any help here [PHP Renaming functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-rename.php) and here [PHP Rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-rename.php)

Comment: Neither `echo` nor `if` are functions.